# stop button for backgroundworker and threadpool

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, threadpool

I have the following functions which work just fine except the stop button. It is stopping the threadpools but when I click again on start it shows that backgroundworker is still busy. Pause is working too.

**How can I stop correctly the backgroundworker and all the threadpools?**

```
    public bool stop = false;
    private object signal = new object();
    private static EventWaitHandle PauseEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);

    private void start_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (this._BackgroundWorker.IsBusy)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("busy", "test", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            return;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //some code
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                starting();
    }



    private void stop_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (start == true)
        {
            stop = true;
            //this._BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
              progressBar1.Value = 0;
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //some code
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
    }


    private void starting()
    {
            ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(5, 5);
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10, 10);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //some code
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            this._BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            this._BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            this._BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }


    private void _BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this._BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //some code
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
           string argument = this.listView1.CheckedItems[i].Text;
           this.DoSend(argument);
        }
    }

    private void DoSend(object sender)
    {
        int activeWorkers = 0;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(E_LIST);
        do
        {
                lock (reader)
                {
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //some code
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                lock (signal) 
                {
                    ++activeWorkers; // keep track of active workers
                }
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                        o =>
                        {
                            myfunction(argument);
                            lock (signal) // signal termination
                            {
                                --activeWorkers;
                                Monitor.Pulse(signal);
                            }
                        }, state);

                lock (signal)
                {
                    while (activeWorkers > 0 || stop == true)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(signal);
                        this._BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
                    }
                }

                this.add();

                crt++;
            }
                //start progressbar
                int iProgressPercentage = (int)(((double)crt / (double)total) * 100);
                if (iProgressPercentage <= 100)
                    _BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(iProgressPercentage);
                //end progresbar

                PauseEvent.WaitOne();   
        }
        while (reader.Peek() != -1);
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: background worker AND threadpool? Why?

Comment: Yes, doesn't a BackgroundWorker run on a ThreadPool thread itself?

Comment: this way the hired coder thought to make it work. I just wanna make the stop button work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think about firing the hired coder.  There is no need to do both of these this way.  It's messy.

For the problem though -

1. You need to call cancel on the background worker and wait for it to stop.
2. You need to add a cancel check inside your for loop.

   ```
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            if (this._BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }

            string argument = this.listView1.CheckedItems[i].Text;
            this.DoSend(argument);
        }
   ```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I already tried that few seconds before checking this thread and it's working correctly if I add the cancellationpending condition after the dosend function. anyways, good answer. P.S. I guess he added the backgroundworker to be able to report progress. dunno